# What can be the regex to match any consecutive occurrence of alphabet A in python3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

It seems simple but i don't know why i can't figure it out.
I have something like this

```
a = r'[a-z]*A{2}[a-z]*'
```

but it is only matching two occurrence of A and i want to match any occurrence of A which are more than one ..
i want to match
raaaf , raafm , kaaaaaaj,

Comment: Use `a = r'[a-z]*A{2,}[a-z]*'`

Comment: And make sure your regex is case-insensitive.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work it also match only two  occurrence of a

Comment: More than one space between words in a line would be `(?<=\w)[ ]{2,}(?=\w)` or see the duplicate question.

Comment: I get it now . It is working, the file that i've been reading words from doesn't contain any word with more than 2 A's . So , i was confused